# Car crash - distance and acceleration no friction or rotation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, displacement

A small model car is released by my hand and goes down a ramp and hits a wall.
There is no friction or air resistance and the car is influenced by -9.8m/s^2 gravity.
Why does the maximum acceleration (caused by impact) increase when the car's travel distance increases?
I understand that the maximum acceleration occurs due to the car slowing down very quickly.
Note: there is no rotation, and the car can't do anything like a break or manually accelerate except automatically go down the ramp due to gravity.

Comment: The only variable that matters is the velocity upon striking the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the model car travels down the ramp, it gains potential energy due to its height above the ground. This potential energy is then converted into kinetic energy as the car accelerates downwards. When the car hits the wall, it comes to an abrupt stop and all of its kinetic energy is converted into deformation energy, which is dissipated through the car and the wall.

The amount of deformation energy depends on the distance over which the car comes to a stop. If the car travels a longer distance before hitting the wall, it will have a greater kinetic energy at impact, and thus more deformation energy will need to be dissipated. This requires a greater force, which leads to a higher acceleration.

In other words, if the car travels a shorter distance before hitting the wall, it will have less kinetic energy and require less force to come to a stop. This results in a lower acceleration.

Therefore, the maximum acceleration that the car experiences during impact increases as the travel distance increases because more deformation energy needs to be dissipated, requiring a greater force and thus a higher acceleration.

To explain in more detail and using mathematical terms, we can consider the equation for the conservation of mechanical energy:

Initial Energy = Final Energy

The initial energy of the ball at the top of the ramp is given by its gravitational potential energy (Ep), which is proportional to its height above the ground and is given by:

Ep = mgh

Where m is the mass of the ball, g is the acceleration due to gravity, and h is the height above the ground. As the ball rolls down the ramp, its potential energy is converted into kinetic energy (Ec), which is given by:

Ec = 1/2 mv^2

Where v is the velocity of the ball.

When the ball collides with the wall, it abruptly comes to a stop and all of its kinetic energy is converted into deformation energy (Ed), which is dissipated through the ball and the wall. The amount of deformation energy depends on the distance the ball travels while it is decelerated to a stop. This distance is called the deformation length (d).

Therefore, we have:

Initial Energy = Final Energy
mgh = 1/2 mv^2 + Ed

The deformation energy (Ed) is proportional to the average force (Fm) exerted on the ball during the collision and the deformation length (d), that is:

Ed = Fm * d

The average force can be calculated from Newton's second law, which relates the force F applied to an object of mass m with its acceleration a, by:

F = ma

At the moment of collision, the ball undergoes a constant deceleration until it comes to a stop. The average acceleration (am) during the collision can be calculated by:

am = Δv/Δt

Where Δv is the change in the ball's velocity during the collision, and Δt is the time it takes for the ball to come to a stop.

From Torricelli's equation, we have:

Δv = -sqrt(2g * d)

The negative sign indicates that the ball's velocity decreases during the collision. Substituting into the equation for average acceleration, we obtain:

am = -sqrt(2g * d)/Δt

The average force exerted on the ball during the collision is then given by:

Fm = ma = -m(sqrt(2g * d)/Δt)

Substituting into the equation for final energy, we obtain:

mgh = 1/2 mv^2 - m(sqrt(2g * d)/Δt) * d

Simplifying, we arrive at the following equation for the maximum velocity of the ball during the collision:

vmax = sqrt(2gh - 4gd/Δt^2)

We can observe that the maximum velocity (and therefore the maximum acceleration) increases when the deformation length (d) increases because this implies that more deformation energy needs to be dissipated during the collision, which requires a greater average force and, therefore, a greater average acceleration.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what deformation energy means?